# Error in using AssetsLibrary.h

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code looks as below in my source code:

```
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary {
   static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
   static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
   dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
   return library;
}
```

When I try to build, it gives error as :

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Setting_Main.o //Setting_Main.o reflects name of my source file          Setting_Main.h
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Now, when I comment some line as below, it does not show error. However, I am not able to get value of library.

```
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary {
   static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
   static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
   //dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    //library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
   // });
   return library;
 }
```

Can anyone suggest me what is exactly going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

This is linker error, you need to add the assets library

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework
```

framework to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the AssetsLibrary framework to the “Link Binary With Libraries” build phase of your target? Sounds exactly like a similar problem i had a couple of weeks ago that had to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it. The error was simply because the AssestsLibrary.framework was also present in my downloads and the program was pointing to that location by default. So, I deleted the framework at downloads and it worked.